# Do you need to call Dispose() on IWindsorContainer?

Tags: .net, castle-windsor, dispose

I just noticed that the IWindsorContainer interface in Castle Windsor includes Dispose().

None of the CastleWindsor tutorials I have seen (e.g. http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/designpatterns/InversionOfControlAndDependencyInjectionWithCastleWindsorContainerPart1.aspx and http://wiki.bittercoder.com/ContainerTutorials.ashx) declare the container in a using block or call Dispose on it.

Should I be calling Dispose() on my container, or does it depend? If the latter, upon what?

Thanks

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes you do.](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Three-Calls-Pattern.ashx)

Comment: Looks like it's related to the container's Release method which will be the subject of my next question.

Comment: So, just to clarify, Disposing of the container calls Dispose (where appropriate) on all the components it has resolved? Is that basically it?

Comment: I suggest reading this documentation page http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.LifeStyles.ashx

Answer (score 0):

The rule is that if something somewhere implements IDisposable, you must dispose of it when you're done with it (and disposing correctly can also [prevent objects from being prematurely finalized](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/13/10049634.aspx)).

Comment: A sensible point, but do you know why the Windsor container needs disposing?

Comment: No, I don't know Windsor. I guess, however, that disposing the container will dispose any contained disposable element.